# Formatting GridView output

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

> EDIT: I have already chosen an answer and it is more applicable than
>   the one being addressed to me.

This is my output using `GridView`:

[image]

And I have this code in my `aspx`:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns ="False" DataKeyNames="art_id">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="art_name" HeaderText="NAME" InsertVisible="false" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="art_id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="art_path" HeaderText="PATH" InsertVisible="false" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="art_id" /> 
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

What I want to happen is that all the paths will be turned into pictures

```
<img src="(the path from database)"/>
```

Is there anyway I can format the output of the database so I could output images?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding Eval with an ImageURL in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135562/binding-eval-with-an-imageurl-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`asp:TemplateField`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield(v=vs.110).aspx) and `asp:Image` like this:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Width="100px" Height="100px" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("art_path") %>'/>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Answer (score 0):

ImageField is made just for this

```
<asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="ImageNameColumn" DataImageUrlFormatString="/images/{0}"></asp:ImageField>
```