# Failed to retrieve image from database. No error when run it~ but no img display at all

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

C# code

```
public partial class photorecognize : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\registerdatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select image from [picture] where username = 'wenhao123'";

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);

        DataListABC.DataSource = dt;
        DataListABC.DataBind();

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

asp.net

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataListABC" runat="server" Height="208px" Width="226px">          
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Database:

[image]

Comment: <asp:DataList ID="DataListABC" runat="server" Height="208px" Width="226px">          
                <ItemTemplate>
                                  
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />

                </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>

Comment: here is my asp code~ sorry for messy post

Comment: The name of an image is not the image. To do what you are asking you would need to make [image] varbinary type and store the actual bytes.

Comment: sorry @Crowcoder can u tell me in more details? sorry about that. I'm very new in c# ~~~~

Comment: the purpose of my coding is ~ get the username's image (only wenhao123) and display it out ~~~

Comment: Lets start with a simpler scenario - if your images are in your site (like in an "images" folder), then you can use your data to bind to the URL. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135562/binding-eval-with-an-imageurl-in-asp-net

Comment: my {image column} data type is {varchar(100)} did i need to chg it?

Comment: I don't know. Your code implies that your images may be stored in your website and the database just holds the name. If so, you can set the `Url` attribute on `asp:Image` by constructing it like in the post I linked to. If your images are not hosted in your site then you must store the bytes of the image in a varbinary column and do [something like this](http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/store-images-to-database-and-bind-to-gridview-in-Asp-Net-1114.aspx)